# Get related order_id in function of wkf button with Odoo

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I have sale.order.recpay

```
class recieved_payments(osv.osv):
    _name = "sale.order.recpay"
    _description = "Recieved Payments"
    _columns = {
        'name_type': fields.selection([('creditcard', 'Credit Card'),('banktransfer', 'Bank Transfer'),('ccbooking', 'CC Booking'),('ccunbocked', 'CC Unbooked'),('cash', 'Cash'),('other', 'Other type')],
        'Type', required=True,),
        'reccieved_amount': fields.float('Amount', required=True,),
        'reccieved_notes': fields.char('Notes'),
        'datepay': fields.datetime('Date', select="1"),
        'payyment_id': fields.many2one('sale.order', 'Payments', ondelete='cascade', required=True, select="1"),
        'user_idpay': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Done by', required=True, select="1"),
}

    _defaults = {
        'user_idpay': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: uid,
        'datepay': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
}
```

tree view of these model inside sale.order xml

and a workflow button

```
<button name="signal_sale_fullpay_fnct" type="object"    states="prepaiiied,prepwaiting" class="oe_highlight" ] string="Full amount recieved"/>
```

and function for window

```
def signal_sale_fullpay_fnct(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if not ids: return []
    dummy, view_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'bcs_bus_gmbh9', 'view_payments_bcs_form_dialog')
    sale_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order')
    paym = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
    return {
        'name':_("Register Payment"),
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_id': view_id,
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': 'sale.order.recpay',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'nodestroy': True,
        'target': 'new',
        'domain': '[]',
        'context': {
            'payyment_id': paym.name,
        }
    }
```

all is working fine, but is one problem!
the main problem is to browse (from sale order from where i create these record) field 'sales order' as default

![these is popup in sales-order where i need that as default will be filled order confirmation field ()][1]

i have tried to use context as above, but that doesnt work

any ideas?!

Comment: I think you will get sale order id in paym.payyment_id.id because you have taken m2o field into your model.

Comment: relation between sale.order and sale.order.recpay is:

in sale.order
'recieved_payments': fields.one2many('sale.order.recpay', 'payyment_id', 'String'),

in sale.order.rec*** 
payyment_id': fields.many2one('sale.order', 'String', ondelete='cascade', required=True, select="1"),

Comment: if paym.payyment_id.id error is - AttributeError: 'sale.order' object has no attribute '_ids'

Comment: You should use active_id, it's always in context. if your current working model is sale order and you are opening popup from there then you can get sale order id in active_id.

Comment: 'context': {
               'payyment_id': paym.active_id.name,
            } how to use active id?

Comment: i need to define active_id but how to do that

Comment: context.get('active_id',False)